# Solving a Laplace Transform Problem

Tags: laplace-transform, partial-fractions

Back to more transforms and need to refresh my brain how to solve these problems. 
I have this problem:

$$ x(0) = 1$$
$$ x'(0) = 2$$
$$ x''(0) = 1$$
$$ x''(t) + 6x'(t) - 5x(t) = 2t $$

If I remember correctly the initial value of x''(t) is not needed until a later exercise, which I think I'll be able to solve if I get help for this part.

I started with LT and got this:
$$ s^2*X(s) -  s - 2 + 6s*X(s) - 6 - 5*X(s) = \frac{2}{s^2}$$ 
which becomes
$$ X(s) = \frac{s^3+8s^2+2}{s^2(s^2+6s-5)} $$
After this I've gotten more uncertain about what to do, maybe partial fraction decomposition?

Comment: Haha that was quick, did you use any software to get the fractions? I got the -2/5 and -12/25 but looked kinda weird so got confused.

Comment: Why delete your answer Moo? Hope you see this...

Answer (score 0):

Just for being able to check your solution
[https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%27%27[t]%2B6*x%27[t]-5*x[t]%3D2*t,+x[0]%3D1,+x%27[0]%3D2](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%27%27[t]%2B6*x%27[t]-5*x[t]%3D2*t,%20x[0]%3D1,%20x%27[0]%3D2)

Provided your calculations are correct, indeed, partial fraction decomposition is one way to go.
Another and maybe faster way might be to solve it via the characteristic equations and not apply the Laplace Transform.

However, your solution is unique if you have give $x(0)$ and $x'(0)$. So if you are not lucky and by coincidence your solution will also satisfy the third condition, it has no solution.

Comment: We have to use the Laplace Transform, but I hate that I get really "ugly" fractions because of the bad expression: X(s)*(s^2+6s-5)